# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Can you please tell me, what is causing this error and how can I fix it?

```
21:38:16 main            SpringApplicati ERROR  Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Class org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider does not implement the requested interface jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
```

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

sourceCompatibility = '17'

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.3.8'
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.30.Final'
    implementation 'jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:3.1.0'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.4.6'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
}
```

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database

spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

github project -> -----------

full stack -> ---------

Comment: Are you overriding the managed version of hibernate-core for a reason? I would suggest to let Spring Boot use the managed version **6.2.2.Final** by removing the version from the implementation declaration

Comment: You can also remove **implementation 'jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:3.1.0'**, it is imported by **hibernate-core**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the error is the dependency

```
implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.30.Final'
```

You are overriding Spring Boot managed dependency with an unsupported version.

You can remove the depencency, Spring Boot will use the managed version **6.2.2.Final**